Minimizing $\left(\frac{c}{a} + \frac{c}{b}\right)^2$, where $c$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs $a$ and $b$
This question is regarding the following problem

Given that $a, b, c$ are the sides of the $\triangle ABC$ which is right angled at $C$, then what is the minimum value of the following expression?
$$\left(\frac{c}{a} + \frac{c}{b}\right)^2$$

My approach to solving the above problem was as follows, i factored out $c$ and we get the following
$$c^2\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right)^2 \tag1$$
$$c^2\left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{2}{ab}\right) \tag2$$
Now using the inverse pythagorean theorem we get
$$c^2\left(\frac{1}{c^2} + \frac{2}{ab}\right) \tag3$$
$$1 + \frac{2c^2}{ab} \tag4$$
Now by using the $AM > GM$ inequality
$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} \tag5$$
$$\frac{c^2+2ab}{4} \geq ab \tag6$$
$$c^2 \geq 2ab \tag7$$
$$\frac{c^2}{ab} \geq 2 \tag8$$
Now using this fact at the equation we obtained earlier we find that the minimum value of the expression in the question happens to be $5$.
However the answer to the above question is given to be $8$ in my book. Am I wrong, or the book? And if I am wrong, then where?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Assuming $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, your quantity is
$$c^2\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{(ab)^2} = c^2\dfrac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{a^2b^2}\geq c^2 \dfrac{(2ab)+2ab}{a^2b^2} = \dfrac{4c^2}{ab} = 4\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{ab} \geq 4 \dfrac{2ab}{ab} = 8.$$
And equality holds iff $a^2+b^2=2ab$, which occurs iff $a=b$.

What is the second step ?

just applying AM-GM, $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$

One thing what is wrong with my answer?

I think the inverse Pythagorean theorem, the formula is incorrect, since it doesnt tell you that $\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}=\dfrac{1}{c^2}$.

Oh yeah thanks it involves the height and not the hypotenuse

Let $\frac ca=\csc\theta$ and $\frac cb=\sec\theta$, where $0<\theta<\frac\pi2$. And $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple. Now,
$$\left(\frac{c}{a} + \frac{c}{b}\right)^2=\left(\csc\theta-\sec\theta\right)^2+4\csc\theta\sec\theta\geq4\csc\theta\sec\theta=\frac{8}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\frac{8}{\sin2\theta}\geq8$$
Hence, the minimum value of the given expression is $\mathbf8$. It occurs when $2\theta=\frac\pi2$ or $a=b$, which is also the condition for the maximum area of a right-angled triangle.

What you want to prove is equivalent to
$$c^2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2\ge 8$$
or
$$c^2\left(\frac{a+b}{ab}\right)^2\ge 8$$
which is same as
$$(a^2+b^2)(a+b)^2\ge 8a^2b^2$$
or
$$(a-b)^2(a^2+4ab+b^2)\ge 0$$
which is obviously true.

Using $A.M. \ge G.M.$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}\right)^2 
& =\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2 \\
& \ge2 \sqrt{a^2 b^2} \left(2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1}{b}}\right)^2 \\
& =8 ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the equality holds iff the triangle is isosceles iff $a=b$ and $c=\sqrt2 a$.

Using Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality
$2c^2 \left(\dfrac{1}{a}+ \dfrac{1}{b} \right)^2 \ge 2(a+b)^2 \left(\dfrac{1}{a}+ \dfrac{1}{b} \right)^2$
$\ge 16$
by AM-GM Inequality
